# Python tkinter return value from function call in a button

Tags: python, tkinter, return-value

Hello I'm new to python and I'm stuck I need help.

My problem is this:
I have a function that returns a string
I call this function in a button
How to get this value ?

My code :

```
from tkinter import* 
from tkinter import filedialog 
file_path = ''
def window(): 
  fen=Tk() fen.geometry('{0}x{1}+{2}+{3}'.format(600, 400, 300, 200)) 
  fen.config(bg = "#87CEEB") 
  return fen 
def select_file(): 
  file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename() 
  return file_path 
def main():  
  fen = window() 
  bouton1 = Button(fen, text = "Select a file", command= select_file()) 
  print(file_path) 
  fen.mainloop() 
main()
```

If I print the file_path in my functions
I can do it, it's perfect,

But I can't get it out of the function

Comment: Ask yourself this: "when does the print statement run, and when does the `window` function run?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the return value when the function is called as the result of an event (button press, etc). The code that calls the function (inside of `mainloop`) ignores the return value.

If other parts of the code need the value, you need to store it as an attribute of an object or as a global variable.

The other problem in your revised code is that you're calling the `print` statement before the user has a chance to click the button, so the value will be blank even if you use a global variable. You have to wait to use the value until after you've clicked the button and selected the file.

For example, create a function that prints the value, and then attach that function to a button. Click your button to choose the file, and then click the button to display the data. As long as you save the value in the first function into a global variable, it will be available in the second function.

Comment: I also tried with a global variable but it does not change anything

Comment: @Toniodaninca: then you are doing something wrong. Setting the global variable absolutely will work. Since you didn't provide an example that illustrates the problem it's impossible for me to know what the problem is.

Comment: @Toniodaninca: please don't put code in the comments. You can edit your question to add more information.

Comment: Yes sorry it's Updated

Comment: Even putting the print after the line fen.mainloop() doesn't work

Comment: @Toniodaninca: yes, of course. `mainloop` doesn't return until the window has been destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

You wont be able to do this as you are, in theory, returning the file path *to the button*.

Use the function to set the variable in an object, or set a global variable.

Additionally, you dont need the lambda before your function call, just call the function without the braces (i.e. command = select_file)

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is a good answer, but it doesn't really add anything to the question that Bryan's answer didn't already (except the `lambda` part, which is just a formatting tip). It's a good idea on SO to avoid duplicate answers, since the information in duplicate answers has already been posted, and since some people see them as good targets for downvotes (that's _not_ a threat; just a heads-up). I suggest you read the [answer] page of the [help] if you haven't already, which explains how to answer questions. You can also read the [tour] for a basic intro to how things work here.

Comment: Yes thanks for lambda but with the global it doesn't work either